# Is there a notion of Global secondary Index in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, couchbase

I understand Mongo supports secondary indexes, but it is local to the shard i.e Every shard will have its own index (containing just the documents in this shard) and those will will be accessed in parallel (every shard reads its own local index shard) and the results merged. I understand couchbase and dynamo has global secondary indexes so Instead of having multiple indexes on multiple nodes, a single node has a single index for the global data. This means an index lookup can be performed against just one node. Is there something similar available for Mongodb ?

I could not find it from mongo's doc https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there is no in-built global secondary index in MongoDB, only the local indexes you mentioned. This is the reason why global indexes are not mentioned in the [docs you linked](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/).

This causes results like [these](https://blog.couchbase.com/2016/june/mongodb-fails-to-perform-runs-out-of-gas) where Couchbase outperforms MongoDB drastically.